# VBA Macros - How to find multiple words within a row?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet containing various column where I need to search a record containing up to 3 words within a single row. I'm trying to create a Macro. I have written the following code but finding difficulty at two places:

1. if `Activecell` is not an exact match but contains some of the words in Textbox1
2. search is never ending and goes in loop

**My Code**

```
Private Sub Findcheck_Click()

Dim rgfound1 As Range
Dim rgfound2 As Range
Dim rgfound3 As Range

GoTo msearch
msearch:

Set rgfound1 = Cells.Find(TextBox1)

Cells.Find(What:=TextBox1, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

If rgfound1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Not Found"
    GoTo mexit
End If

If ActiveCell.Value = TextBox1 Then
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select

    Set rgfound2 = Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Find(TextBox2)
    If rgfound2 Is Nothing Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        GoTo msearch
    End If

    Set rgfound3 = Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Find(TextBox3)
    If rgfound3 Is Nothing Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        GoTo msearch
    Else
        MsgBox "Found"
    End If

End If

mexit:

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: how does your sheet's data structire looks like ? can you add a screen-shot of it ? or et us know which columns allways have data ?

Comment: it is generic, any column may contained the data

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but if the value from `TextBox1` is in your worksheet, but the values from either `TextBox2` or `TextBox3` cannot be found in your worksheet, you have a `GoTo` statement that says to go and repeat the process again - which will still only find the value from `TextBox1` but not `TextBox2` and/or `TextBox3`, and around the loop you go again.

Comment: Sr No | Name | Country | Qualification | Role
------------- | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
1 | Rahul | France | Graduate | manager
2 | Max | USA | Graduate | manager
3 | Joe | France | Medical | assistant
4 | Joel | India | Architect | assistant
5 | Rao | England | PMP | assistant
6 | Raj | England | Graduate | manager
7 | Max | USA | Graduate | CEO
8 | Santa | Dubai |  | Global Head
9 | Sameer | India | Inter | assistant
10 | Max | Australia | Inter | assistant

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use as much of your original code, and use the `Find` method in order to find all 3 values inside the `User_From` `TextBox`es ,and also kept the `GoTo msearch`, etc...

It's always a good idea to stay away from `Activate`, `ActiveCell` and `Select`, and to work with refferenced object as `Sheets("Sheet1")`, and `Range`s.

I also added the `With` statement to make sure the code is searching for the sheet with your data, and not `ActiveSheet`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Findcheck_Click()

Dim Rngfound1 As Range
Dim Rngfound2 As Range
Dim Rngfound3 As Range
Dim FindRng As Range

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name (where you want to search for the 3 words)
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ' init row number
    i = 1

    ' find last row with data in Column A >> you might need to modify to another column
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

msearch:

    Set FindRng = .Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(LastRow, 5))
    Debug.Print FindRng.Address

    If i > LastRow Then GoTo mexit

    ' loop through all rows from row 2 till last row with data
    Set Rngfound1 = FindRng.Find(What:=TextBox1.Value)

    If Rngfound1 Is Nothing Then
        GoTo mexit
    Else
        ' successfult find of TextBox1 >> save the row number
        i = Rngfound1.Row
    End If

    Set Rngfound2 = .Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Find(TextBox2.Value)
    If Rngfound2 Is Nothing Then
        Set Rngfound1 = Nothing
        i = i + 1
        GoTo msearch
    End If

    Set Rngfound3 = .Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Find(TextBox3.Value)

    If Rngfound3 Is Nothing Then
        Set Rngfound1 = Nothing
        Set Rngfound2 = Nothing
        i = i + 1
        GoTo msearch
    Else
        MsgBox "Found at row" & i
        Exit Sub
    End If

End With

mexit:
MsgBox "Not Found"

End Sub
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd1Ty.png)

User_Form parameters I entered to search:

[image]

Result I got running the code above:

[image]

Comment: Not working...it is searching the first Textbox continously...also pls check the image of the table I have attached

Comment: @Shakil  I'll test it with your sample data, what is the name of this Worksheet?

Comment: You can try any name...let it be MasterTable

Comment: @Shakil see my edited answer above, and screen-shots of running this code

Comment: Thanks for response. When we enter USA Graduate and CEO it goes in never ending loop

Comment: @Shakil you didn't take the latest code version, i saw that, modifed the line ` Set Rngfound1 = .Cells.Find(What:=TextBox1.Value, After:=.Range("A" & i + 1),` , added the +1 to i .Try copying this latest version and run some tests.

Comment: Yes got it but when we enter Joe England and Graduate it is going in loop whereas it should say Not found

Comment: sorry, I can't duplicate your error since there is no such data in the table you've provided.

Comment: i know that the data is not there thus the error should get prompt

Comment: so what is missing ? you are not getting the `MsgBox` with "Not Found" ?

Comment: No i m not getting the message box

Comment: I got it...after adding  x As Long --  If x = 0 Then
        x = i
        Else
            If x = i Then
                MsgBox "Not Found"
                GoTo mexit
            End If
        
    End If

Comment: @Shakil if you want, try edited code, changed a little of the logics, but tested it a few times and given my stabile correct results

Answer (score 0):

edited after realizing OP code was in a `UserForm`...

you could try this code:

```
Private Sub Findcheck_Click()
    Dim rgfound As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim rowValsString As String

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange '<--| reference currently active sheet "used" range only
        Set rgfound = .Find(What:=TextBox1.Text, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                 LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                 MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) '<--| try finding 'TextBox1' text

        If Not rgfound Is Nothing Then '<--| if found
            firstAddress = rgfound.Address '<--| retrieve first found range address
            Do
                rowValsString = "|" & Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Rows(rgfound.Row).Value)), "|") & "|" '<--| retrieve the found range whole "used" cells content in one string delimiting values with "|"
                If InStr(rowValsString, "|" & TextBox2.Text & "|") > 0 And InStr(rowValsString, "|" & TextBox3.Text & "|") > 0 Then '<--| if other two textboxes texts found in the row values string
                    MsgBox "Found row: " & rgfound.Row
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                Set rgfound = .FindNext(rgfound) '<--| try finding next cell with TextBox1
            Loop While rgfound.Address <> firstAddress '<--| loop until wrapping back on first found range
        End If
    End With
    MsgBox "Not Found"
End Sub
```

You'd better substitute `ActiveSheet` with the actual data worksheet reference, like `WorkSheets("mySheetName")` changing `"mySheetName"` to your actual data sheet name

Comment: this is to be run for table which is in xls format there is no  | (pipes). Check the attached table (image)

Comment: don't worry about pipes, they're just for internal variables matching purposes. Try it

Comment: "run time error. object required" at setfound = .find

Comment: 1) there's no `Setfound =.find`, while there's a `Set rgfound = .Find(What:=TextBox1.Text, LookIn:=xlFormulas,...` 2) Have you put the code in the relevant worksheet code pane?

Comment: Now I got you are in a UserForm context, while I believed you had `ActiveX` worksheet controls. See edited code

Comment: good idea of transposing and getting the value but when all 3 values are present it says not found

Comment: I tested with your values you gave in comments and it worked. may be you post a screenshot of your data to see how they actually look like

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @shai and @user3598756 for your help

### the final code is as given below

Option Explicit

Private Sub Findcheck_Click()

Dim Rngfound1 As Range
Dim Rngfound2 As Range
Dim Rngfound3 As Range

Dim LastRow As Long, i, x As Long

' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name (where you want to search for the 3 words)
With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    ' init row number
    i = 1

```
' find last row with data in Column A >> you might need to modify to another column
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

GoTo msearch
```

msearch:

```
' loop through all rows from row 2 till last row with data
Set Rngfound1 = .Cells.Find(What:=TextBox1.Value, After:=.Range("A" & i + 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
            False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Rngfound1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Not Found"
    GoTo mexit
Else
    ' successfult find of TextBox1 >> save the row number
    i = Rngfound1.Row
'-
If x = 0 Then
    x = i
    Else
        If x = i Then
            MsgBox "Not Found"
            GoTo mexit
        End If

End If
'-
End If

Set Rngfound2 = Rows(Rngfound1.Row).Find(TextBox2.Value)
If Rngfound2 Is Nothing Then
    GoTo msearch
End If

Set Rngfound3 = Rows(Rngfound1.Row).Find(TextBox3.Value)
If Rngfound3 Is Nothing Then
    GoTo msearch
Else
    Rows(i).Select
    MsgBox "Found on Row No     " & i

End If
```

End With

mexit:

End Sub

Comment: usualy it is custume on SO to mark as "Answer" the other users that helped you fixing your code, so mark (and/or upvote)  either @user3598756 answer or mine